# Creating matrix with the new rows formed in 2nd dataframe wrt 1st dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix

```
data1 = { 'node1': [1,1,1,2],
     'node2': [2,3,5,4],
     'weight': [1,1,1,1], }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['node1','node2','weight'])

data2 = { 'node1': [1,1,2,3],
     'node2': [4,5,4,5],
     'weight': [1,1,1,1], }
df2= pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['node1','node2','weight'])
```

I would like to create a matrix with the the 1's in the matrix indicating the new rows formed in the second dataframe.
For example- 2 4 is a row which is in both the dataframes so in the matrix we put matrix[2,4]=0 and [4,2]=0 as the relation is bidirectional.

2) 1 4 is a new row in the second dataframe which is not in the 1st dataframe so we put matrix[1,4]=1 and [4,1]=1

3)If a combination doesnt appear like [3,4] in both the dfs then its matrix[3,4]=matrix[4,3]=0

Expected Output:

```
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
```

Comment: So if a combination doesn't appear in df1, that implies you set the value to 1, correct?

Comment: Yes.If a row is present in df2 but not df1 then it is 1

Comment: What if a combination does not appear in both?

Comment: If the combination is not there in any then its 0 .Like in the above example [3,4] is not present therefore matrix[3,4]=matrix[4,3]=0

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you how to generalise it to bigger data, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `node*` columns as indexers into a `numpy` array, this can be done pretty easily.

```
# Adapting Divakar's answer to my question here (with thanks) 
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/46990063/4909087 

m = pd.concat([df1, df2]).max().max()
v = np.zeros((m, m))

idx1 = df2.iloc[:, :-1].values - 1
idx2 = df1.iloc[:, :-1].values - 1

v[tuple(np.r_[idx1,idx1[:,::-1]].T)] = 1
v[tuple(np.r_[idx2,idx2[:,::-1]].T)] = 0

v
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

---

If you want the output in a dataframe, call the `DataFrame` constructor:

```
pd.DataFrame(v, np.arange(m) + 1, np.arange(m) + 1, dtype=int)

   1  2  3  4  5
1  0  0  0  1  0
2  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  1
4  1  0  0  0  0
5  0  0  1  0  0
```

Comment: what are idx1 and idx2?

Comment: @Code_ninja Thanks for asking. They were defined in older versions of the post one would've seen through the edit history. My mistake that I forgot to add it back when updating the post.

Comment: v=np.zeros((m,m)) gives memory error when working on large datasets. Do you have a fix?Thanks

Comment: @ChaitaliSarkar What is the value of `m` in that case?

Comment: The value of m is 96575

Comment: @ChaitaliSarkar Yeah, you'd need a 18GB array. That's just not possible. I think you should look at a sparse matrix. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html  When you have a matrix of mostly zeros, and are setting only certain values to 1, this is definitely what you want to look at.

Comment: Once you create a sparse matrix, you can set and query values just as you would a normal array. It's just that the internal memory representation is _much_ more compact.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ How to change this answer to a sparse matrix representation?

Comment: @ChaitaliSarkar Take a look at this: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html

Answer (score 2):

BY using `pandas`..

```
df=pd.concat([df1,df2],keys=['old','new'])
df=df.drop_duplicates(['node1','node2'],keep=False).loc['new']
df=pd.crosstab(df.node1,df.node2).reindex(index=[1,2,3,4,5],columns=[1,2,3,4,5]).fillna(0)
pd.DataFrame(df.values.T+df.values,index=[1,2,3,4,5],columns=[1,2,3,4,5],dtype=int)
Out[894]: 
   1  2  3  4  5
1  0  0  0  1  0
2  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  1
4  1  0  0  0  0
5  0  0  1  0  0
```

Comment: + `astype` for neat output!

Comment: How to generalize this answer for big datasets?