# A neater way to set values at indexes with NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array initially with zeros, like this:

```
v = np.zeros((5, 5))
v

array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

I also have a set of arrays `idx1` and `idx2`.

```
idx1

array([[0, 3],
       [0, 4],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 4]])

idx2

array([[0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 4],
       [1, 3]])
```

Look upon each pair of values as row and column indices. So, for example, in `idx1`, the first pair `(0, 3)` would be indexers into `v[0, 3]` and so on.

I want to first set values at indexes specified by `idx1` to `1`, followed by all indexes specified by `idx2` to `0`.

Also, please note that if there is a pair `(i, j)` in some array, I want to set `v[i, j]` and `v[j, i]` at the same time.

My final result becomes:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

I currently achieve this by doing:

```
def set_vals(x, i, j, v):
    x[i, j] = x.T[i, j] = v

v = np.zeros((5, 5))

i1, j1 = idx1[:, 0], idx1[:, 1]
i2, j2 = idx2[:, 0], idx2[:, 1]

set_vals(v, i1, j1, 1)
set_vals(v, i2, j2, 0)

v     #  the result
```

However, I believe there might be a better way. Would love to hear any thoughts/suggestions for improvement. Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for improvement performance wise? Would `v` always be initialized as zeros?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Sorry about the confusion. I neglected to mention `I forget to mention that if there is a pair (i, j) in some array, I want to set v[i, j] and v[j, i] at the same time.`. Edited that in.

Comment: @Divakar Performance wise I don't think anything can beat this but I'd be interested to know if at all it is possible. And yes, `v` is always initialised to 0 in my case.

Comment: So, then better as in "cleaner/shorter"?

Comment: @Divakar yes, a more "numpaic" way... as they'd say :-) Also, if you were to tell me it is not possible, I'd believe you, because if anybody knew enough to say that, it would be you... and that would constitute a valid answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In search of a more "compact" way of expressing it, I got this -

```
v = np.zeros((5, 5))
v[tuple(np.r_[idx1,idx1[:,::-1]].T)] = 1
v[tuple(np.r_[idx2,idx2[:,::-1]].T)] = 0
```

---

On python3.6+, you can use the `*` unpacking operator to reduce this further:

```
v[[*np.r_[idx1,idx1[:,::-1]].T]] = 1
v[[*np.r_[idx2,idx2[:,::-1]].T]] = 0
v

array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: Made a small edit to your answer, hope that's okay! Your answer is just what I needed.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ It needed that. Thanks!